# Reference property in nested method

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I must not be thinking of how to search for this correctly.

I want to be able to reference the parent key in the compare method.

```
{
    title: 'Pageviews',
    key: 'pageviews',
    dataIndex: 'pageviews',
    sorter: {
        compare: (a, b) => a.pageviews - b.pageviews, //dynamically add key name of outer key
        multiple: 2,
    }
}
```

I have to be able to do it directly within the object

Comment: Use regular instead of arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you're trying to do is access some sort of an instance of an object or some sort of structure. I would recommend using a class in this case if you wanted to go down the Object-Oriented approach. Otherwise, there are other options you can do with functional state.